# How to match a string with dots in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to match a set of strings that follow a certain pattern using re. However, it fails at some point.

Here are the strings that fails

```
string1= "\".A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J\""
string2= "\".K.Y.C.A.N.Y.W.H.I.A.W...1.B...1.1.7\""
string3= "\"Testing using quotes func \"quot\".\"": 
string4= "A.b.e.f. testing test":
```

Here is my approach:

```
"".join(re.findall("\.(\w+)", string1))
```

Here are my expectations:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJ"
"KYCANYWHIAW.1B.117"
"Testing using quotes func \"quot\"."
"A.b.e.f. testing test"
```

It only works for the first string

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'(\.)*\.([A-Z0-9])', r'\1\2', string1)`?

Comment: are you only trying to match or do you want to substitute? (`string1` and `string2`) are missing dots in your expectation? What is your pattern? A `.` followed by anything not a whitespace-character (matching `string3` like `re.sub(r'\.([^.])', r'\g<1>', string1)`) or followed by something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]` as @WiktorStribiżew wrote?

Comment: What are your rules for substitution?  From your examples it seems to me that the rules include:  (1) If the sequence of chars is proceeded and followed by  \ and if the . is followed by a Capital Letter, remove the dot, else ignore the dot.  Is this correct?

Comment: Also, your string3 and string4 definitions have trailing : characters that should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given examples, one option is to remove the dots while asserting what is directly to the right is either an optional dot followed by a char A-Z or a digit 0-9.

Note that `\w` would also match a-z.

```
\.(?=\.?[A-Z0-9])
```

**Explanation**

- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `\.?[A-Z0-9]` Optionally match a dot and a char A-Z or digit 0-9
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cYOCqW/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EBnjRm)

**Example code**

```
import re

strings = [
    "\".A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J\"",
    "\".K.Y.C.A.N.Y.W.H.I.A.W...1.B...1.1.7\"",
    "\"Testing using quotes func \"quot\".\"",
    "A.b.e.f. testing test"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r"\.(?=\.?[A-Z0-9])", '', s))
```

**Output**

```
"ABCDEFGHIJ"
"KYCANYWHIAW.1B.117"
"Testing using quotes func "quot"."
A.b.e.f. testing test
```

---

Another option could be specify the different rules for the pattern matching an alternation. For example using multiple occurrences of the dot and leaving a single one between `W.1` and `B.1`:

```
(?<!\d)\.+(?=[A-Z.])|(?<=\d)\.+(?=[A-Z\d])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9UoeF/1)